# Create Test in this following Controller

Tags: unit-test, controller, class, query, attachment

How to create a test class from this controller?

```
public List<Event_Logo__c> getEventLogo() {
      con = new List<Event_Logo__c>(); 
      con = [SELECT Id, (Select Id, Name,
                                    LastModifiedDate 
                               From Attachments 
                               Order By LastModifiedDate DESC) 
               FROM Event_Logo__c WHERE Event__c = :eventId];
      return con;
}
```

Comment: Seems like you're missing code. For example, how is the variable "eventid" defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a test class. You can find the sample code format from salesforce website.

2) insert the Event__c records and set the variable eventId.

3) Insert the record Event_Logo__c and attachment for it.

4) Initiate the class in which this methods defined. Call the method with class object.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_example.htm